# Before fragment launches how to show popup window in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

Hi I have a issue with two views in Fragment .I have a scenario like login button.click on the login button should move to the Navigationview activty.Inside Navigation Activity And then redirecting to HomeFrgament.

Now in the HomeFragment I am display a popup window without onclick means top of the Homefragment I am displaying popup window .

Now My Popup window is not showing.

Can any one help me

LoginActivity.java:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationViewActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
            }
        });
```

NavigationViewActivity.java:

```
 Fragment fragment = new HomeNurseFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("myHospitalList", myList);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        loadFragment(fragment);
```

HomeNurseFragment.java:

```
public class HomeNurseFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button patient_list,book_appointment,doctor_list,hospital_list;
    private ArrayList<String> hospitalNames;

    private ArrayList<HospitalData> hospitalDataList=new ArrayList<HospitalData>();
    public HomeNurseFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_coordinatorhome, container, false);
        patient_list=rootView.findViewById(R.id.patient_list);
        book_appointment=rootView.findViewById(R.id.book_appointment);
        doctor_list=rootView.findViewById(R.id.doctor_list);
        hospitalNames=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<HospitalData> transactionList = (ArrayList<HospitalData>)getArguments().getSerializable("myHospitalList");
        for (HospitalData hospitalList1 : transactionList) {
            String Hospitalid = hospitalList1.getId();
            String HospitalName = hospitalList1.getName();
            Log.d("Hospitalid", Hospitalid);
            Log.d("HospitalName", HospitalName);
            HospitalData hospitalDataList1 = new HospitalData(Hospitalid, HospitalName);
            hospitalDataList.add(hospitalDataList1);
            hospitalNames.add(HospitalName);

            final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, hospitalNames) {// dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.borderdashboard.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        // Disable the first item from Spinner
                        // First item will be use for hint
                        // spinnerlocation.setPrompt("Select");

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;

                    if (position + 1 == 0) {
                        // Set the hint multipart/form-data color gray

                        tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    } else {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup_hospitallist, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button save = popupView.findViewById(R.id.save);
                    Button cancel = popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                    Button close = popupView.findViewById(R.id.close);
                    MaterialSpinner hospital = popupView.findViewById(R.id.hospital);
                    hospital.setHint(Html.fromHtml(hospital.getHint() + " " + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"));
                    hospital.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                     popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                }
        
        return rootView;
    }

  
}
```

Exception:

```
Process: com.example.gehs, PID: 19813
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1122)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:439)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1621)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1375)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1341)
        at com.example.ihm.HomeNurseFragment.onCreateView(HomeNurseFragment.java:119)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3472)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Comment: Why you commented "popupWindow.showAtLocation()"?? Without this the Popup will not be shown. However are you sure to create and show a PopupWindow, at Fragment creation, for each items in the "transactionList"? If there are 10 items in the List it will show 10 PopupWindows each one OVER the others....

Comment: @emandt there it is giving me an error

Comment: We are unable to help you about "an error"...........

Comment: popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); uncommennted this line not giving me any error

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: @emandt posted my error

Comment: I don't think you want to open a PopupWindow for each item in "transactionList" at the creation of the Fragment because there could be a situation with 10 items, so 10 PopupWindows all above the others. So I thinkg you need to change strategy.... However on "Fragment.onCreateView()" the Fragment is not attached to Activity yet, so each PopupWindow you create in that precise moment cannot be showed at that time. You have to wait until "Fragment.onAttach()" event is called.

Comment: can you please edit my code how to slove some suggestion please

Comment: First I think you have to choose/define how manage multi-PopupView when "transactionList" contains more than one HospitalData.

Comment: any example please